# Is It In Its Prime?

Tags: functional-programming, primes, f#

Just because I'm bored, I wrote yet another prime number generator. I think it's pretty clean, but I won't be surprised if someone finds something to comment on.

```
let isPrime (knownPrimes :int list) currentNumber =
    List.forall (fun i -> currentNumber % i <> 0) knownPrimes

let rec primes knownPrimes currentNumber =
    match isPrime knownPrimes currentNumber with
    | true ->
        Console.WriteLine(currentNumber)

        primes (currentNumber::knownPrimes) (currentNumber + 2)
    | false -> primes knownPrimes (currentNumber + 2)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Console.WriteLine(2)
    primes [2] 3 |> ignore
    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing something consecutively to the console is of very little value. OK, `primes` returns a list of primes, but you really can't use them until all primes are calculated in the domain of `int`, and that's a lot.

For instance, it is useless to write

```
primes [2] 3  |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.iter (printfn "%i")
```

because it will not return before all primes are calculated.

It is btw strange that the client of the `primes` has to figure out that 2 is a prime :-): `primes [2] 3 |> ignore`

You could change the function to take a max or a count value to stop the generator when enough is enough.

As an alternative it is IMO more useful to return a `Seq` of primes, because it returns the primes as soon as they are individually calculated:

```
let enumPrimes = 
    let rec primes currentNumber knownPrimes =
        match isPrime currentNumber knownPrimes with
        | true -> 
            seq { 
                yield currentNumber 
                yield! (primes (currentNumber + 2) (currentNumber::knownPrimes))
            }            
        | false -> primes (currentNumber + 2) knownPrimes 

    seq {
        yield 2
        yield! [2] |> primes 3 
    }
```

---

When determine if a number is a prime, it is only necessary to check primes up to (inclusive) the square root of the number:

```
let isPrime currentNumber knownPrimes =
    let sqrtNum = sqrt (float currentNumber) |> int
    knownPrimes |> List.rev |> List.takeWhile (fun p -> p <= sqrtNum) |> List.tryFind (fun p -> currentNumber % p = 0) = None
```